# (IndexError: list index out of range)

Tags: python, python-3.x

While making this simple program, I encountered this error that seems to be related to lists. However, I don't really know how to fix it properly.

PS: if you could give me a few pointers or maybe ways I could make my program better that be cool.

```
def getOrder():
    mainDish = ["Burger", "Pizza", "Taco", "Italian Sandwich"]
    mainDish_Price = [3.55, 7.99, 12.99, 5.99]
    drink = ["Cola", "Pepsi", "Sprite", "Water"]
    drink_Price = [0.80, 0.60, 0.30, 0.20]
    sideDish = ["French Fries", "Onion Rings", "Salad", "Chips"]
    sideDish_Price = [1.25, 2.99, 1.75, 2.25]

    myOrder_Count = []
    myOrder_Cost = []
    qty_Count = []

    fullPrice = 0
    total_Drink_Order = 0
    total_MainDish_Order = 0
    total_SideDish_Order = 0
    count = 0
    i = 0

    while(True):
            print("AI : Resturant Bot Options.")
            print("AI : Choose [1] For Main Dish.")
            print("AI : Choose [2] For Sides.")
            print("AI : Choose [3] For Drinks.")
            print("AI : Choose [4] For Getting Reciept.")
            print("AI : Choose [5] For Exit.")

            choice = int(input("Select Your Choice : "))
            
            if(choice == 1):
                print("\n" + "AI:"
                    "\n\n1 : Burger               $3.55"
                    "\n\n2 : Pizza                $7.99"
                    "\n\n3 : Taco                 $12.99"
                    "\n\n4 : Italian Sandwich     $5.99")

                mainDish_Order = int(input("\n\nAI: Select Your Choice. "))
                qty = int(input("AI: Please Enter The Quantity.  "))
                if(mainDish_Order == 1):
                    myOrder_Count.append(mainDish[0])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(mainDish_Price[0])
                    count += 1
                    total_MainDish_Order += mainDish_Price[0] * qty
                
                elif(mainDish_Order == 2):
                    myOrder_Count.append(mainDish[1])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(mainDish_Price[1])
                    count += 1
                    total_MainDish_Order += mainDish_Price[1] * qty
                
                elif(mainDish_Order == 3):
                    myOrder_Count.append(mainDish[2])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(mainDish_Price[2])
                    count += 1
                    total_MainDish_Order += mainDish_Price[2] * qty
                
                elif(mainDish_Order == 4):
                    myOrder_Count.append(mainDish[3])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(mainDish_Price[3])
                    count += 1
                    total_MainDish_Order += mainDish_Price[3] * qty
                
            if(choice == 2):
                print("\n" + "AI: " + 
                    "\n\n1 : French Fries               $1.25"
                    "\n\n2 : Onion Rings                $2.99"
                    "\n\n3 : Salad                      $1.75"
                    "\n\n4 : Chips                      $2.25")

                sideDish_Order = int(input("AI : Please Select Your Choice."))
                qty = int(input("AI: Please Enter The Quantity : "))
                if(sideDish_Order == 1):
                    myOrder_Count.append(sideDish[0])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(sideDish_Price[0])
                    count += 1
                    total_SideDish_Order += sideDish_Price[0] * qty
                    
                elif(sideDish_Order == 2):
                    myOrder_Count.append(sideDish[1])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(sideDish_Price[1])
                    count += 1
                    total_SideDish_Order += sideDish_Price[1] * qty
                    
                elif(sideDish_Order == 3):
                    myOrder_Count.append(sideDish[2])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(sideDish_Price[2])
                    count += 1
                    total_SideDish_Order += sideDish_Price[2] * qty
                    
                elif(sideDish_Order == 4):
                    myOrder_Count.append(sideDish[3])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(sideDish_Price[3])
                    count += 1
                    total_SideDish_Order += sideDish_Price[3] * qty
                
            if(choice == 3):
                print("\n" + "AI :" 
                    "\n\n1 : Cola                   $0.80"
                    "\n\n2 : Pepsi                  $0.60"
                    "\n\n3 : Sprite                 $0.40"
                    "\n\n4 : Water                  $0.20")

                drink_Order = int(input("AI : Select Your Choice : "))
                qty = int(input("AI: Please Enter The Quantity : "))
                if(drink_Order == 1):
                    myOrder_Count.append(drink[0])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(drink_Price[0])
                    count += 1
                    total_Drink_Order += drink_Price[0] * qty
                    
                elif(drink_Order == 2):
                    myOrder_Count.append(drink[1])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(drink_Price[1])
                    count += 1
                    total_Drink_Order += drink_Price[1] * qty
                    
                elif(drink_Order == 3):
                    myOrder_Count.append(drink[2])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(drink_Price[2])
                    count += 1
                    total_Drink_Order += drink_Price[2] * qty
                    
                elif(drink_Order == 4):
                    myOrder_Count.append(drink[3])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(drink_Price[3])
                    count += 1
                    total_Drink_Order += drink_Price[3] * qty
            fullPrice = total_MainDish_Order + total_SideDish_Order + total_Drink_Order

            if(choice == 4):
                print("..")
                time.sleep(2)
                print("...")
                time.sleep(3)
                print("....")
                time.sleep(3)
                
                print("AI: Here's Your Reciept")
                print("            ")
                print("**************")       
                while(i < count):
                    print(f"Items : {myOrder_Count[i]}")
                    print(f"Cost : ${myOrder_Cost[i]}")
                    print(f"qty : {qty_Count[i]} \n")
                    i += 1
                
                print("**************")
                print(f"AI: The Final Cost Is ${fullPrice}")
                exit()

            if(choice == 5):
                print("AI: System Shutdown.")
                exit()

getOrder()
```

Comment: You posted way too much code with way too little explanation about the error you receive. Read [ask] and especially how to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Since you asked for ways to make your progam better: respect the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/); `if`, `elif` and `while` are not functions so drop the parentheses; [`exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/constants.html?highlight=exit#exit) should only be used in the interactive interpreter shell; your function does too much and so has too many code lines; ...

Answer (score 1):

the problem in your code is that the list `qty_Count` is always empty so when the code tries to run the line `print(f"qty : {qty_Count[i]} \n")` when the list is empty it doesn't find the index so the program crashes.

I couldn't find where you store any data in that list so either find a way to solve that - by inserting data to the list - or remove that part from being printed.

Edit: This code works without problems.

```
import time
def getOrder():
    mainDish = ["Burger", "Pizza", "Taco", "Italian Sandwich"]
    mainDish_Price = [3.55, 7.99, 12.99, 5.99]
    drink = ["Cola", "Pepsi", "Sprite", "Water"]
    drink_Price = [0.80, 0.60, 0.30, 0.20]
    sideDish = ["French Fries", "Onion Rings", "Salad", "Chips"]
    sideDish_Price = [1.25, 2.99, 1.75, 2.25]

    myOrder_Count = []
    myOrder_Cost = []
    qty_Count = []

    fullPrice = 0
    total_Drink_Order = 0
    total_MainDish_Order = 0
    total_SideDish_Order = 0
    count = 0
    i = 0

    while(True):
            print("AI : Resturant Bot Options.")
            print("AI : Choose [1] For Main Dish.")
            print("AI : Choose [2] For Sides.")
            print("AI : Choose [3] For Drinks.")
            print("AI : Choose [4] For Getting Reciept.")
            print("AI : Choose [5] For Exit.")

            choice = int(input("Select Your Choice : "))
            
            if(choice == 1):
                print("\n" + "AI:"
                    "\n\n1 : Burger               $3.55"
                    "\n\n2 : Pizza                $7.99"
                    "\n\n3 : Taco                 $12.99"
                    "\n\n4 : Italian Sandwich     $5.99")

                mainDish_Order = int(input("\n\nAI: Select Your Choice. "))
                qty = int(input("AI: Please Enter The Quantity.  "))
                qty_Count.append(qty)
                if(mainDish_Order == 1):
                    myOrder_Count.append(mainDish[0])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(mainDish_Price[0])
                    count += 1
                    total_MainDish_Order += mainDish_Price[0] * qty
                
                elif(mainDish_Order == 2):
                    myOrder_Count.append(mainDish[1])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(mainDish_Price[1])
                    count += 1
                    total_MainDish_Order += mainDish_Price[1] * qty
                
                elif(mainDish_Order == 3):
                    myOrder_Count.append(mainDish[2])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(mainDish_Price[2])
                    count += 1
                    total_MainDish_Order += mainDish_Price[2] * qty
                
                elif(mainDish_Order == 4):
                    myOrder_Count.append(mainDish[3])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(mainDish_Price[3])
                    count += 1
                    total_MainDish_Order += mainDish_Price[3] * qty
                
            if(choice == 2):
                print("\n" + "AI: " + 
                    "\n\n1 : French Fries               $1.25"
                    "\n\n2 : Onion Rings                $2.99"
                    "\n\n3 : Salad                      $1.75"
                    "\n\n4 : Chips                      $2.25")

                sideDish_Order = int(input("AI : Please Select Your Choice."))
                qty = int(input("AI: Please Enter The Quantity : "))
                qty_Count.append(qty)
                if(sideDish_Order == 1):
                    myOrder_Count.append(sideDish[0])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(sideDish_Price[0])
                    count += 1
                    total_SideDish_Order += sideDish_Price[0] * qty
                    
                elif(sideDish_Order == 2):
                    myOrder_Count.append(sideDish[1])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(sideDish_Price[1])
                    count += 1
                    total_SideDish_Order += sideDish_Price[1] * qty
                    
                elif(sideDish_Order == 3):
                    myOrder_Count.append(sideDish[2])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(sideDish_Price[2])
                    count += 1
                    total_SideDish_Order += sideDish_Price[2] * qty
                    
                elif(sideDish_Order == 4):
                    myOrder_Count.append(sideDish[3])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(sideDish_Price[3])
                    count += 1
                    total_SideDish_Order += sideDish_Price[3] * qty
                
            if(choice == 3):
                print("\n" + "AI :" 
                    "\n\n1 : Cola                   $0.80"
                    "\n\n2 : Pepsi                  $0.60"
                    "\n\n3 : Sprite                 $0.40"
                    "\n\n4 : Water                  $0.20")

                drink_Order = int(input("AI : Select Your Choice : "))
                qty = int(input("AI: Please Enter The Quantity : "))
                qty_Count.append(qty)
                if(drink_Order == 1):
                    myOrder_Count.append(drink[0])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(drink_Price[0])
                    count += 1
                    total_Drink_Order += drink_Price[0] * qty
                    
                elif(drink_Order == 2):
                    myOrder_Count.append(drink[1])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(drink_Price[1])
                    count += 1
                    total_Drink_Order += drink_Price[1] * qty
                    
                elif(drink_Order == 3):
                    myOrder_Count.append(drink[2])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(drink_Price[2])
                    count += 1
                    total_Drink_Order += drink_Price[2] * qty
                    
                elif(drink_Order == 4):
                    myOrder_Count.append(drink[3])
                    myOrder_Cost.append(drink_Price[3])
                    count += 1
                    total_Drink_Order += drink_Price[3] * qty
            fullPrice = total_MainDish_Order + total_SideDish_Order + total_Drink_Order

            if(choice == 4):

                
                print("AI: Here's Your Reciept")
                print("            ")
                print("**************")       
                while(i < count):
                    print(f"Items : {myOrder_Count[i]}")
                    print(f"Cost : ${myOrder_Cost[i]}")
                    print(f"qty : {qty_Count[i]} \n")
                    i += 1
                
                print("**************")
                print(f"AI: The Final Cost Is ${fullPrice}")
                exit()

            if(choice == 5):
                print("AI: System Shutdown.")
                exit()

getOrder()
```

Comment: if I wanted to increment the qtr_Count for each item in the {choice}, do you have any idea how I could go on about it? because as you saw {myOrder_Count} and {myOrder_Cost} were incremented each time the user selects a certain item.

Comment: Add `qty_Count.append(qty)` each time you call `qty = int(input("AI: Please Enter The Quantity : "))` to store the data. It worked when I tested it. I updated my post with a script that works.

Comment: Your welcome! :) If my answer helped you I would really appreciate a upvote and mark as a solution. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

For the list of out range, you don't append to qty_Count.
You can also get rid of elif just use _Order number as an index. Also, iterate over print when you only change food and price.
Example:

```
        if(choice == 1):
            print("\n" + "AI:", end="")
            for food, price in zip(mainDish, mainDish_Price):
                print(f"\n\n1 : {food:20} ${price}")

            mainDish_Order = int(input("\n\nAI: Select Your Choice. "))
            qty = int(input("AI: Please Enter The Quantity.  "))
            myOrder_Count.append(mainDish[mainDish_Order-1])
            myOrder_Cost.append(mainDish_Price[mainDish_Order-1])
            count += 1
            total_MainDish_Order += mainDish_Price[mainDish_Order-1] * qty
            qty_Count.append(qty)
```

Answer (score 0):

I quite enjoyed looking at your script, I remember doing similar stuff.
If you are at the stage of using functions, and it looks like you are, then I would suggest that you go with that a bit more and make your program more modular and break it down instead of everything in one function, it makes debugging a lot easier.

Comment: For some reason, modules don't work for me. I make a new file and add a new function to it and then import it in the main file but it doesn't respond for some reason.

Comment: For Example, I wanted to put the item prices and the "side variables" in another file and then import it.

Comment: I am sorry I can not instruct you, but I would encourage you to try to use a greater number of functions and break your code down into smaller chunks, e.g. one function for input one for output and one for calculations would make your code more readable and easier to debug.

Comment: I'll try doing that, thank you very much.